# Doing nested aggregations in elasticsearch via Clojure and elastich

Tags: elasticsearch, clojure

I am struggling to find examples of doing [nested elasticsearch aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-aggregation.html) using [elastich 2.2.1](http://clojureelasticsearch.info/). I have looked through [the source tests](https://github.com/clojurewerkz/elastisch/tree/master/test/clojurewerkz/elastisch/rest_api/aggregations) for examples but only find non-nested aggregations.

My documents are tweets, each document includes a timestamp and a sentiment score. Here is how my namespace looks:

```
(ns tweets.core
  (:require [clojurewerkz.elastisch.rest :as es-rest]
            [clojurewerkz.elastisch.rest.document :as es-doc]
            [clojurewerkz.elastisch.query :as es-q]
            [clojurewerkz.elastisch.rest.response :as es-rsp]
            [clojurewerkz.elastisch.aggregation :as es-agg]
            [clojure.pprint :as pp]))

(clojure.core/refer 'clojure.core)
```

This code works as expected, retrieving some tweets over a given week, having a given keyword:

```
(defn get-some-tweets
  [kwd]
  (let [conn (es-rest/connect local-es-host)
        res  (es-doc/search conn indices mapping
               :query (es-q/filtered :query (es-q/query-string :query kwd)
                        :filter (es-q/range :timestamp :from "2015-11-19"
                                                       :to "2015-11-24")))]
```

And I can use a [date_histogram](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/search-aggregations-bucket-datehistogram-aggregation.html) to get weekly counts of tweets like this:

```
(defn counts-by-week
  [kwd]
  (let [conn (es-rest/connect local-es-host)
        res  (es-doc/search conn indices mapping
               :query (es-q/query-string :query kwd)
               :aggregations {:weekly-data (es-agg/date-histogram :timestamp "week")})]
    (pp/pprint (get-in res [:aggregations]))))
```

Here is the nested aggregation that is not working. I am trying to bucket tweets by week, and then get sentiment stats within each weekly bucket:

```
(defn avg-weekly-sentiment
  [kwd]
  (let [conn (es-rest/connect found-es-host {:basic-auth found-auth})
        res  (es-doc/search conn indices mapping
               :query (es-q/query-string :query kwd)
               :aggregations {:weekly-data (es-agg/date-histogram :timestamp "week")
                              :weekly-avg (es-agg/avg "sentiment")})]
    (pp/pprint (get-in res [:aggregations]))))
```

This returns a map containing the count of docs by week, along with a single `weekly-avg` key, the value of which I have confirmed is the overall average sentiment.

This approach of nesting leads to an error:

```
(defn avg-weekly-sentiment2
  [kwd]
  (let [conn (es-rest/connect found-es-host {:basic-auth found-auth})
        res  (es-doc/search conn indices mapping
               :query (es-q/query-string :query kwd)
               :aggregations {:weekly-data (es-agg/date-histogram :timestamp "week")
                              :aggregations {:weekly-avg (es-agg/avg "sentiment")}})]
    (pp/pprint (get-in res [:aggregations]))))
```

The error is

> "Could not find aggregator type [weekly-avg] in [aggregations]\"

So... I am relatively new to using elasticsearch's DSL, and even newer to Clojure. I have not found any examples of nested aggregations using the Clojure wrapper, but it looks like [this has been supported since 2.2.0](http://blog.clojurewerkz.org/blog/2016/01/04/elastisch-2-dot-2-0-is-released/). I am sure I am missing something simple but for the life of me I cannot figure it out (I am not showing several other attempts).

UPDATE: The elastich Google Group pointed out that there may be an issue with using the HTTP client vs the native client. Sure enough, I [found an example in the test repo for the native client](https://github.com/clojurewerkz/elastisch/blob/master/test/clojurewerkz/elastisch/native_api/aggregations/date_histogram_aggregation_test.clj). I'll adapt my code, post results, and close the question if I am successful...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to switch to using the native client and then I followed the example in the elastich test repo, linked to in the UPDATE of the question. Here is what the code looks like now...

```
(ns tweets.core
  (:require [clojurewerkz.elastisch.native :as es-native]
            [clojurewerkz.elastisch.native.document :as es-doc]
            [clojurewerkz.elastisch.native.response :as es-rsp
            [clojurewerkz.elastisch.query :as es-q]
            [clojurewerkz.elastisch.aggregation :as es-agg]
            [clojure.pprint :as pp]))

(clojure.core/refer 'clojure.core) 

(def ^:private local-es-nhost [["<the-IP-of-the-ES-server>" 9300]])
;; Note the use of port 9300 instead of 9200 used with the HTTP client
(def ^:private local-cluster {"cluster.name" "elasticsearch"}) 
;; You can get the cluster name from  curl <es-server>:9200/_nodes/cluster
;; The default name is "elasticsearch"
```

After switching to the native client, the average-sentiment-by-week query looks like:

```
(defn avg-weekly-sentiment
  "I would have never guessed to use (merge ...) were it not for the elastich test code"
  [kwd]
  (let [conn (es-native/connect local-es-nhost local-cluster)
         res (es-ndoc/search conn indices mapping
               :query (es-q/query-string :query kwd)
               :aggregations {:weekly (merge {:aggs {:avg_sentiment (es-agg/avg "sentiment")}}
                                        (es-agg/date-histogram "timestamp" "week"))})]
    (pp/pprint (get-in res [:aggregations]))))
```

This yields results like:

```
{:weekly
 {:buckets
  [{:doc_count 3572,
    :key
    #object[org.elasticsearch.common.joda.time.DateTime 0x6eaa586c "2015-10-12T00:00:00.000Z"],
    :avg_sentiment {:value 0.39169344904815234}}
   {:doc_count 4934,
    :key
    #object[org.elasticsearch.common.joda.time.DateTime 0x3fed225f "2015-10-19T00:00:00.000Z"],
    :avg_sentiment {:value 0.7119037292257783}}
   {...
    }]}}
```